# Automatic weight painting doesn't affect mesh

Tags: mesh, armature, weight-painting

I have an IK armature set up to move a very simple arm around, but after pairing the mesh to the armature using Ctrl+P then selecting automatic weights it seems as though nothing happens. I select the lower_arm and go into weight painting and nothing is there. I'm not sure if its a problem with the mesh I made since I made it myself from a sphere then sculpted it, or if its something else. The file is attached for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before assigning a mesh to an armature, the deforming bones have to be marked as deforming by checking **deform**. When creating bones, this checkbox is enabled by default, you must have unchecked it at some point.

[image]

After that, select the mesh, then <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> select the Armature and Parent them <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> e.g. with *Automatic Weights*. Note, how vertex groups are created for the bones, which have **Deform** checked.

[image]

To ensure deformation, the **Deform** must stay checked and the Armature modifier (created by the parenting earlier) must be visible.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I was following a tutorial and they had unchecked deform, but I forgot to recheck it. Hindsight is 20/20 I suppose!

Comment: @MichaelO Great on solving the problem. If this answer helped you, you can mark it as accepted by checking the arrow on its left.